# Cutting intersecting objects into separate objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have many intersecting circles and lines. How can I cut all of these objects and lines into individual shapes for fill/colouring? [I've done this many times before, [weeks ago] but now, I just can't remember.]

{I may have labouriously created each shape separately before - is there a command that will 're-attach' all the line segments into the new smaller shapes?}

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your original objects and your desired result so we don't have to guess what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is the Divide tool in Pathfinder. It's the one in the bottom corner that is highlighted:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wikimandia. [I'm back from hospital emergency - it was Sunday - no local doctors were available here.].... I searched for 'pathfinder' and found a YouTube in Arabic using a simpler circular design. It guided me to 'Windows' before 'Pathfinder' [I'm just starting Illustrator.] Now I'm happy.